# Redirect URLs in WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

I changed the structure of my permalinks and now I want to redirect the following type of URL

```
/year/month/post-name
```

to this

```
/post-name
```

is that possible to do within WordPress or with htaccess?

Comment: You typically do not need to do any redirects with that kind of permalink change; Wordpress will handle it. Remove the regex rewrite rule suggested by anubhava, and then try an old /year/month/post-name link and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place this rule as **your very first redirect rule** (just below `RewriteEngine` line):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?\d{4}/\d{2}/([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

# rest of the WP rules
```

Comment: Interestingly enough on my development version I've implemented some other solution which works but apparently it's either not live on the live site or it's not working there

Comment: What is exact URL are you using for testing? Did you place this rule as first rule as suggested?

Comment: I am using the following url http://imagecurve.local/ and I did place it as first rule

Comment: I've found a solution see my answer

Comment: Ah you had month in digits not like `jan,feb.mar` that's why it wasn't working. See my updated rule. btw doing same via php code is pretty expensive that doing it via `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution which I've implemented on my development version but which has probably been deleted from the live version due to WordPress updates here it is.

Place the following before any other code in the /index.php of your WordPress installation

```
// redirect old style links to the new ones
if (preg_match("/\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\//", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
{
    $newURI = '/' . preg_replace("/\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\//", '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    header("HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently");
    header('Location: ' . $newURI);

    exit;
}
```